# Cannot go to the next page

Tags: java, android

I have a custom listView which is using a BaseAdapter class. And I have an array which has a list of HashMaps. Those Hashmaps (String, Object) includes bitmaps and some strings (those strings may have HTML tags) in it.

OnItemClickListener action is working well if I do not use putExtra on my Intent code - or putExtra("String", "String"). But, when I load hashMap in putExtra, it goes to the previous page instead of going the next page. And there is an awkward thing that if the position equals 1, it goes to next page without any issue. Otherwise (0,2,3,4,5,6..) it goes back to the previous page and in debugging mode; on performItemClick action, mOnItemClickListener returns null in AdapterView.java.

Here is my code:

```
    // Menu Action
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ServicesAndProducts.this, ServicesAndProductsDetail.class);
        HashMap<String, Object> map = servicesAndProductsList.get(position);
        intent.putExtra("SelectedMap", map);
        //intent.putExtra("String", "Esra"); // is working

        //Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        //extras.putSerializable("SelectedMap", servicesAndProductsList.get(position));
        //extras.putString("Title", title);
        //intent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

LogCat:

```
07-12 11:44:35.083 2675-2675/esrakarakecili.autoking I/Choreographer: Skipped 1736 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-12 11:44:35.254 2675-3064/esrakarakecili.autoking D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa4463380 (ListView) with handle 0xaec39b00
07-12 11:44:35.523 4603-4603/esrakarakecili.autoking E/InstantRun: IO Error creating local socket at esrakarakecili.autoking
                                                                   java.io.IOException: Address already in use
                                                                       at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.bindLocal(Native Method)
                                                                       at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.bind(LocalSocketImpl.java:306)
                                                                       at android.net.LocalServerSocket.<init>(LocalServerSocket.java:48)
                                                                       at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server.<init>(Server.java:94)
                                                                       at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server.create(Server.java:88)
                                                                       at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.onCreate(BootstrapApplication.java:358)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4553)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
07-12 11:44:35.688 4603-4603/esrakarakecili.autoking W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-12 11:44:35.709 4603-4626/esrakarakecili.autoking D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                       [ 07-12 11:44:35.714  4603: 4603 D/         ]
                                                                       HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb42f4a00, tid 4603
07-12 11:44:35.724 4603-4603/esrakarakecili.autoking D/Atlas: Validating map...
07-12 11:44:35.801 4603-4626/esrakarakecili.autoking I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-12 11:44:35.816 4603-4626/esrakarakecili.autoking D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
07-12 11:44:35.825 4603-4626/esrakarakecili.autoking W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-12 11:44:35.825 4603-4626/esrakarakecili.autoking W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb4341a40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Comment: show logcat . problem for `NullPointerException`

Comment: Ok, thank you I've added my logcat now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I matched datas on my hashMaps and solved my issue.

The point was that it was working on position 1, and not working on other positions of my array. So I compared the datas of hashmaps and realized that bitmaps' resolutions were different - 300x300 and 480x480. 480 pixels were too big to send to the other page.

But still wondering what could be done if needed too big bitmap.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I guess you didn't retrieve the data properly.

```
// To get the object in second Activity
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("SelectedMap");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The second class wasn't starting yet because there was an error before going to the next page. I solved the issue by decreasing bitmap sizes.